# AWS Glue what is optimal data size for ETL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am planning to use AWS Glue for my ETL process, and have custom python code written and run as a AWS Glue Job.

I found in AWS Glue documentation, that by default, AWS Glue allocates 10 DPU per job.Is there a maximum limit of DPUs for a job, (I do not see anything in the LIMITs section, i.e., Max of DPUs per Job limits).

Or is there any optimal data size in MB / GB, that is recommended to avoid any Out of memory error issue.  Please clarify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Glue API docs, the max you can allocate per Job execution is 100 DPUs.

> AllocatedCapacity – Number (integer).
>   The number of AWS Glue data processing units (DPUs) allocated to runs of this job. From 2 to 100 DPUs can be allocated; the default is 10. A DPU is a relative measure of processing power that consists of 4 vCPUs of compute capacity and 16 GB of memory. For more information, see the AWS Glue pricing page.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed this section.

Comment: @Yuva The limits aren't the same for Python Glue jobs which you plan to write. There you can have maximum 1 DPU.

Answer (score 1):

The limits aren't the same for Python Glue jobs (which the OP plans to implement) where you can have maximum 1 DPU. Below is the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#create-job-python-properties) (as of Aug 2019)

> The maximum number of AWS Glue data processing units (DPUs) that can be allocated when this job runs. A DPU is a relative measure of processing power that consists of 4 vCPUs of compute capacity and 16 GB of memory. For more information, see the AWS Glue pricing page.
>
> You can set the value to 0.0625 or 1. The default is 0.0625.